# Clone Wordpress website with same database

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to clone my wordpress website on a different folder .

so lets say there is **www.abc.com** 
I want to have **www.abc.com/desktop** - both websites would be same - one would be responsive - other would NOT be responsive and I want both of them to use the same database.

How will I be able to do that.

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you doing such thing? Just in case, if you know something like "responsive=mobile"; responsive serves desktop version on desktop,  mobile version on mobile, according to the screen sizes.

Comment: Sounds like an X-Y problem...

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to comment on this - I do know responsive = mobile - maybe my way of asking was wrong - My target is to have the website **www.abc.com** 
When opened on mobile phones, it should have below, **view full site** - which redirects them to a desktop version of the site - how will that be achievable then?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a comment allready: A responsive webside servers desktop and mobile alike. So one responsive webside is all you need, no copys.

Beside that: you should not run two wordpress in different places on one database. Wordpress stores things like relativ paths and the path-structure in the database. If you chang it in one side it would change in the other aswell. You would kill all your links with that. Plugins could have simular Problems, when they store information the database.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to comment on this - I do know responsive = mobile - maybe my way of asking was wrong - My target is to have the website **www.abc.com** 
When opened on mobile phones, it should have below, **view full site** - which redirects them to a desktop version of the site - how will that be achievable then?

Comment: You could use a `$_GET` parameter to load a different CSS. But usaully there is an option in a mobile browser to load the desktop version anyway.